# pandas dataframe; error during converting NaN to 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The last step of my dataframe is to convert all NaN values to 0 (zero). My dataframe contains more than 1000 columns, some are text, some are integers, and some are floats. 
To convert NaN to 0, I use the following command:

```
#replace nan in columns with 0
nan_cols = df5c.columns[df5c.isnull().any(axis=0)]
for col in nan_cols:
    df5c[col] = df5c[col].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

This worked fine, until I added a new column with new data, which gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonscript_v8.py", line 233, in <module>
    df5c[col] = df5c[col].fillna(0).astype(int)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2632, in astype
    dtype=dtype, copy=copy, raise_on_error=raise_on_error, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2864, in astype
    return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2823, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 430, in astype
    values=values, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 472, in _astype
    values = com._astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 2463, in _astype_nansafe
    return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
  File "pandas/lib.pyx", line 935, in pandas.lib.astype_intsafe (pandas/lib.c:16612)
  File "pandas/src/util.pxd", line 60, in util.set_value_at (pandas/lib.c:66830)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NODE_1_length_402490_cov_43.5825_ID_1'
```

What does this error mean, and how can I solve this?

My dataframe looks like this:

```
source       contigID                               contig_length   SCM/genes   plasmid_genes/genes   A053_1    parA_1
COLS157_1   NODE_1_length_402490_cov_43.5825_ID_1   402490           0.87         0.95                NaN         NaN
COLS157_10  NODE_10_length_218177_cov_45.105_ID_19  218177           0.79         0.97                NaN         NaN
COLS157_100 NODE_157_length_248_cov_34.4628_ID_313  248              NaN          NaN                 NaN         NaN
COLS157_11  NODE_11_length_176130_cov_51.1495_ID_21 176130           0.75         0.86                NaN         NaN
COLS157_12  NODE_12_length_165446_cov_50.2044_ID_23 165446           0.77         0.88                NaN         NaN
```

Comment: It means you have the value `'NODE_1_length_402490_cov_43.5825_ID_1'` in one of the columns and pandas cannot convert that to integer. It is not the fillna part but `.astype(int)` that raises the error.

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking at the data but it looks like you are trying to convert a string to an int. It's likely due to the fact you are looping over the entire column if any of the values in a given column are missing. Can you post some of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly this will work.

```
nan_cols = df5c.columns[df5c.isnull().any(axis=0)]

for col in nan_cols:
    for i in range(len(df5c)):
        if pd.isnull(df5c.loc[i, col]):
            data.loc[i, col] = data.loc[i, col] = 0
```